# Ironpython Winforms KeyPress Enter

Tags: winforms, ironpython

Community,

i'm a complete noob in programming but i've learned quite a lot from stackoverflow (i hope...)

### my question:

i'm working with ironpython and trying to create a GUI. Currently i'm struggling to get the KeyPress Event to work. I have TextBox and if someone presses the "Enter Key" it should do something. Like starting another function.

I'm using the IDE PyCharm to code.

I appreciate your help with this question. Thanks in advance :)

Here is what i've tried so far (just an example, not the real code):

```
import clr

# Set references
clr.AddReference("System.Drawing")
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")

# Import Winforms
from System.Drawing import *
from System.Windows.Forms import *

class MyClass(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Text = "MyGui"
        self.Size = Size(500, 500)
        self.CenterToScreen()

        self.create_textbox()

    def create_textbox(self):
        mytxtbox = TextBox()
        mytxtbox.Name = "Textbox1"
        mytxtbox.Location = Point(50, 50)
        mytxtbox.Size = Size(100, 25)

        mytxtbox.KeyPress += KeyPressEventHandler(self.press)

    def press(self, sender, args):
        key = args.KeyChar
        if key == Keys.Enter:
            print("You pressed Enter in the TextBox")

# Run this thang
form1 = MyClass()
Application.Run(form1)
```

Comment: Well, start a function.  Not print(), pretty hard to see in a GUI app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use KeyDown to get Enter key, instead of KeyPress:

```
mytxtbox.KeyDown += on_enter

def on_enter(self, e, args):
    key = e.KeyChar
    if key == Keys.Enter:
        print("You pressed Enter in the TextBox")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)
i changed the function to:
def on_enter(self, sender, args):
    key = args.KeyCode
and then the "if" part.